# Android Studio: wanna show preview of item but it shows default information in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to put item which consists of title and comment on screen. (wanna make notes App)
So I used RecyclerView to show it can be updated when I touch.
I was confused about catching some grammer errors related to ViewBinding on Activity, Fragment and **Adapter**.
Many QNAs in here are helpful to solve grammer errors. but if I touched item, it doesn't work.

Code is here:

```
class NotesAdapter(val notes: List<Note>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NoteViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteViewHolder {
        val binding = NoteLayoutBinding
            .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return NoteViewHolder(
            binding,
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.note_layout, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = notes.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.textViewTitle.text = notes[position].title
        holder.binding.textViewNote.text = notes[position].note

        //Update existed Note
        holder.view.setOnClickListener {
            val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionAddNote()
            action.note = notes[position]
            Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action)
        }
    }

    class NoteViewHolder(var binding: NoteLayoutBinding, var view: View)
        :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
}
```

But When I change argument from `binding.root` to `view` in `NoteViewHolder`,
I can edit item If I touched it. But item's preview shows default information which I set in `note_layout.xml`, not item's info.

Could anyone help me please? If you don't have enough information in here, please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few corrections, it will work fine.

```
    class NotesAdapter(val notes: List<Note>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NoteViewHolder>(){
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteViewHolder {
            val binding = NoteLayoutBinding
                .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

/*
return NoteViewHolder(
            binding,
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.note_layout, parent, false)
        )


this is not required, since you are using viewbinding, and you have already inflated binding
LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.note_layout, parent, false)
*/

            return NoteViewHolder(binding)
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount() = notes.size
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.binding.textViewTitle.text = notes[position].title
            holder.binding.textViewNote.text = notes[position].note

             //holder.view.setOnClickListener, you inflated binding and you are listening 
             //to some other view

            //Update existed Note
            holder.binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionAddNote()
                action.note = notes[position]
                Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(action)
            }
        }
    
        class NoteViewHolder(var binding: NoteLayoutBinding)
            :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
    }
```

Comment: Wow! It works! thank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: in my case  holder.binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionAddNote()
                action.note = notes[position]
action.note not working

Comment: @yooooonly  can you share your code with me  or share the solution of my problem